# SwiftUI textfield font size shrink when empty text field

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two text fields which accepts only numbers. Every time text changes in one field am updating the other as well. If I clear the editing text field, the font size of placeholder shrinks. Using observedObject to track text change and updating in another text field. [image]

```
VStack{
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("FROM")
                            .kerning(5.0)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.6))
                            .font(Font.system(size: self.hSize == .compact ? 24 : 48))
                            .bold()
                        TextField("amount", text: self.$textBindingManagerFROM.text
                            , onEditingChanged: {(val) in
                                self.textBindingManagerFROM.editing = true
                                self.textBindingManagerTO.editing = false
                        })
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .allowsTightening(true)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
                            .font(Font.system(size: self.hSize == .compact ? 24 : 48))
                            .frame(minHeight: self.hSize == .compact ? 50 : 100, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                    VStack{
                        Text("TO")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                            .font(Font.system(size: self.hSize == .compact ? 24 : 48))
                            .bold()
                            .kerning(5.0)
                        TextField("amount", text: self.$textBindingManagerTO.text, onEditingChanged: {(val) in
                                self.textBindingManagerFROM.editing = false
                                self.textBindingManagerTO.editing = true
                            })
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .allowsTightening(true)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
                            .font(Font.system(size: self.hSize == .compact ? 24 : 48))
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }

@ObservedObject var textBindingManagerFROM = TextBindingManager(limit: 12, _editing: false)
    @ObservedObject var textBindingManagerTO = TextBindingManager(limit: 16, _editing: false)
```

Comment: As far as I recall (seems I met this already) it is known bug. You can file one more feedback to Apple to push it a bit ahead.

Comment: I see. Ok, thanks for the info. I will do. Saved my time